# Inserting and deleting elements from vector *at the same time*

Tags: c++, performance, vector, insert, erase

**Goal**

Consider a sorted std::vector `x`. We want to erase from this vector all elements at positions indicated by vector `positionsToErase`. We also want to insert the values of vector `valuesToInsert` at positions `positionsToInsert`.

These deletions and insertions must happen *at the same time*, in the sense that if we erase first, then it will invalidates the positions at which we want to insert values (and vice-versa). I think that will be made clear with the below example

**Example**

Example of function definition

```
template<typename T>
void insertEraseAtPositions(
   std::vector<T>& x,                       // vector to modify. Is sorted and must remain sorted
   std::vector<T>& valuesToInsert,          // is not sorted
   std::vector<size_t>& positionsToInsert,  // is not sorted. This could be figured out inside the function but I happen to already know the positions at which values must be inserted
   std::vector<size_t>& positionsToErase    // is not sorted
);
```

Note that non are constant and modifications can be made in-place.

Example of arguments

```
std::vector<int> x = {0, 10, 20, 21, 30, 50, 60, 70, 81, 90}; // vector to modify
std::vector<int> valuesToInsert = {40, 80, 100}; // Values to insert are '40', '80' and '100'    
std::vector<size_t> positionsToErase  = {3, 8};   // Erase elements '21' and '81'
std::vector<size_t> positionsToInsert = {5, 8, 10};  // Insert where are currently located the elements '50', '81' and past the current last element.
```

Expected output

```
x = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
```

**Important notes**

Performance is very important and it is hence not possible to insert and erase one-by-one (even if we progressively modify positions accordingly) as it would involve way too many copies (or move).

Typically, `x` is of size 1,000 to 100,000. `positionsToInsert` (and `valuesToInsert`) are of size 1-20 and `positionsToErase` is of size 1-5. `x` typically has a capacity that allows inserting the values without reallocating. I hence expect (but might be wrong) that modifications in-place would be faster.

I can also supply iterators instead of indices (`std::vector<std::vector<T>::iterator>` instead of `std::vector<size_t>`) for `positionsToErase` and `positionsToInsert` if you prefer.

**Current work**

I wrote a code to insert at positions but I failed to include the possibility to erase too. Here is the code in case it helps.

```
// Return indices representing the order of elements
template <typename T>
std::vector<uint32_t> sort_indices(const std::vector<T> &v) {

  // initialize original index locations
  std::vector<uint32_t> idx(v.size());
  std::iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);

  // sort indexes based on comparing values in v
  std::sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(),
       [&v](uint32_t i1, uint32_t i2) {return v[i1] < v[i2];});

  return idx;
}

template <typename T>
void reorder(std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<uint32_t>& order)  
{   
    auto v2 = v;
    for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; i++)
    {
        v[i] = v2[order[i]];
    }
}

//// Insert multiple elements at specified positions into vector
template<typename T>
void insertAtPositions(std::vector<T>& x, std::vector<T>& values, std::vector<size_t>& positions)
{
  // assert values and positions are the same size
  assert(values.size() == positions.size());

  // Special case - values is empty
  if (values.size() == 0) return;

  // Special case - single value to insert
  if (values.size() == 1)
  {
    x.insert(positions.front(), values.front());
    return;
  }

  // sort the values and the positions where those values should be inserted
  auto indices = sort_indices(positions);
  reorder(positions, indices);
  reorder(values, indices);

  // Special case - x is empty
  if (x.size() == 0)
  {
      x.swap(values);
      return;
  }
  
  // Allocate memory to x
  x.resize(x.size() + values.size());
  
  // Move things to make room for insertions and insert
  int pos_index = positions.size()-1;
  for (size_t i = x.size()-1 ; pos_index >= 0 ; --i)
  {
    if (i == positions[pos_index] + pos_index)
    {
      // A new value should go at index i
      x[i] = std::move(values[pos_index]);
      --pos_index;
    } else
    {
      // The value from index 'i-pos_index-1' must go to index 'i'
      x[i] = std::move(x[i-pos_index-1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why must they happen at the same time? Is this some assignment/homework restriction, or are you really up to the maximum performance? If the latter holds, why such a restriction? Anyway, does your algorithm need to be _in-place_, or can it operate with a copy of the input vector (which may be faster in practice).

Comment: @DanielLangr I am really up to the maximum performance. I am author of a simulation software in population genetics and, for some simulation scenario, this insertion-deletion step is an important slow part of the code and I want to improve that. Yes, all inputed vectors can be modified at will (see end of section **Example**). I added info about typical input vector size in section **Important notes**. Because inserting the elements are unlikely to require reallocation of `x` memory, I expect (but might be wrong) that in-place modification would be faster.

Comment: @Remi.b - What are the operations that happen the most? Are you focusing on many writes, few reads or are reads just as common as writes?

Comment: @Detonar Reads of `x` are more common than writes `x` (hence the reason for using a vector instead of a deque, although I have questioned this choice).

Comment: I would definitely first try to work with a second auxiliary vector. If you first sort the arrays with positions/values to be erased and inserted, you can then construct the output in the auxiliary vector in a single pass over the input vector elements. You can then try alternative approaches and compare them with this initial solution. (Note that the auxiliary vector can be kept alive such as by making it `static` or `thread_local`, which will avoid allocation each time this task has to be done, and also will improve cache efficiency.)

Comment: Maybe it would be enough to split your vector in multiple smaller ones. Each representing another section or your range of values. This way you could work on different vectors and don't invalidate operations in another range.

Comment: BTW, what is `T` in your application? The efficiency of different approaches might depend on it. Can it be moved? Or copied cheaply?

Comment: @DanielLangr `T` is just a primitive type. It is `uint32_t`. I probably should have just written `uint32_t`. Ok, so I would write into a `static` vector and then swap the `static` vector with `x`, right?

Comment: Swap or copy. Here is some live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/946PrKM7r.

Comment: @DanielLangr Nice. Thank you! Do you want to make an answer out of your comments (stating that I should not try to do in-place modifications) and of your code?

Comment: @Remi.b I don't have time right now but, basically, I just coded what was suggested in my comment as well as in Sorin's answer. You can accept this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying it in place is a no-go.

Consider that you have to insert something at every position. You would need to copy every single item into a temp place then copy them back.

You might argue that you could do it from the end, backwards. But if we have some deletions we would also need to store some of the elements there, potentially getting back to copying every element into some temp storage and back.

I think the fastest way would be to allocate a new array, and build it up, using the original as temp storage. This way you are guaranteed that each element is copied exactly once.

Now, depending on the types used (like ints, or pointers) this could be a lot faster than anything else you might cook up. If copies are expensive consider using moves, or pointers.

If you are worried about performance, you should benchmark you code and tune it. It's hard to argue precisely about performance without data.